# Serializing and Deserializing multiple classes into one JSON object? Without attribute tags

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I'm working on a project where I've been trying to keep code as modular as possible.

I want to now save/load objects to JSON, however I do not want every single class to be saved in hundreds of files as I want the json to be readable and easy to edit in one place for users.

For the sake of example, here is a sample of the C#:

```
 public class ObjectToBeSerialized
 {
     public float aNumber;
 }

 public class LinkingClass
 {
     public ObjectToBeSerialized linkedObject;
     public string aString;
 }

 public class OtherLink
 {
     public ObjectToBeSerialized linkedObject;
     public bool isThisObjectNice;
 }
```

So if I serialized this, the outcome I'm looking for would be like so:

> {   "aNumber": 0,   "aString": "Hello World",   "isThisObjectNice":
>   true }

So that it looks like it's **one** object to someone editing the json but in the code it is still a highly separated series of parts.

It is also important not to use attribute tags to keep the JSON separate from the code. I'm looking to use a ContractResolver or similar.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NielsNet at the moment I'm just basically string-building the json which is obviously really messy and hard to maintain.

Comment: Seems to me you are thinking the wrong way around. If you have an object you want to serialize, then you better have a reference to the linkinClass and the OtherClass. As you mention you want to keep things together.

Comment: I assume that by "keeping JSON separate from the code" you mean keeping it separate from your domain model? This is a good idea, and in your case, the simplest solution would be to create a special lightweight class that would look exactly the way you want your JSON to look, and manually map your domain objects to and from this class.

Comment: By the way, `linkedObject` in the `LinkingClass` might be different from the `linkedObject` in the `OtherLink` class - how are you choosing which one to serialize?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "keeping JSON separate from the code" you mean that you want to separate your domain model from any JSON serialization concerns, I think it's a good idea. The simplest way of doing it would be introducing a lightweight class for the purpose of modelling your output, as well as a mapping function:

```
public class ModelOfWhateverJsonShouldLookLike
{
    public float aNumber { get; set; }
    public string aString { get; set; }
    public bool isThisObjectNice { get; set; }
}

public static ToJsonModel(LinkingClass linkingObject, OtherLink otherLinkObject)
{
    return new ModelOfWhateverJsonShouldLookLike
    {
        aNumber = linkingObject.aNumber, // otherLinkObject.aNumber?
        aString = linkingObject.aString,
        isThisObjectNice = otherLinkObject.isThisObjectNice
    };
}
```

Before serializing, you would have to simply call the mapping function rather than serializing your domain objects.

The advantage of this approach is transparency and simplicity: it is easy to see exactly what is being serialized and debug the mapping function if things go wrong. Using a more "magical" approach with e.g. ContractResolver, might save some boilerplate with larger objects, but becomes a real pain (and a time-killer) when things go wrong.

An unrelated note: I would recommend sticking to C# naming conventions in C# code and naming public properties using UpperCamelCase: `IsThisObjectNice`. If you absolutely don't want to use a JsonProperty attribute, then you could keep the lowercase property names in the `ModelOfWhateverJsonShouldLookLike`.